# I have spatraster stack, how can I update the max value for each layer?

Tags: r, geospatial, raster, terra

I have spatraster stack, how can I update the max value for each layer with a value from a seperate dataframe? The names of rasters match the column names in the dataframe.

I'm very new to R and terra, but so far I have tried writing a for loop but my computer crashes.

Here is my code

```
for (i in 1:nlyr(rast)) {
  layer_values <- winter_rastI[[i]]
  layer_values[layer_values == 1] <- maxvalues[i]
  rast[[i]] <- layer_values
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When asking an R question, please include a *minimal, self-contained, reproducible example*. That is, inlcude data that ships with R, or create some example data with code. If you do not know how to do that, see the terra help files and most of the Q/A on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Example data

```
library(terra)
s <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))  / 1:3 
newvals <- c(800, 500, 200)
```

Get the max values

```
# efficient if the max is already available
mx <- minmax(s, compute=TRUE)[2,]
# alternative 
#mx <- global(s, max)[,1]
```

Use a loop

```
r <- s
for (i in 1:nlyr(r)) {
    r[[i]] <- subst(r[[i]], mx[i], newvals[i])
}
r
```

or lapply

```
r <- lapply(1:nlyr(s), \(i) subst(s[[i]], mx[i], newvals[i]))
r <- rast(r)
```